# Java & Selenium Web Scraping Field Input Text doesn't work

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

My Code:

```
driver.manage().window().maximize();
    
    Duration pageLoadTimeout = Duration.ofMinutes(1);
    driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(pageLoadTimeout);
    
    driver.get("https://deutsche-giganetz.de/");
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, pageLoadTimeout);
    
    wait.until(webDriver -> ((JavascriptExecutor) webDriver)
                    .executeScript("return document.readyState")
                    .equals("complete"));
    
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/section/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/button[1]")).click();
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/header/div/div/nav/div/div[1]/div[2]/ul/li[1]/a")).click();
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    
    
    assert driver.getWindowHandles().size() == 1;
    
        WebElement jetztBestellenButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/main/div[8]/div/section/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[5]/a"));
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", jetztBestellenButton);
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        
        
        driver.findElement(By.name("deliveryAddress.zip")).sendKeys("20095");
```

The element cannot be found on the page. As soon as the script clicks on a link and is redirected to a new page it is supposed to enter something on a field, but this does not work. I have tried everything.

I have tried the path `findElement by.` with everything, with id, class, XPath and none of it worked. I switched from `geckodriver` to `chromedriver` thinking it was the browser, but it wasn't that either. I also wrote a code that loads the page so that the path can be found, but it didn't work either.

The error code each time is that item cannot be found, for example: `"no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"*[name='deliveryAddress.zip']"}"`

Answer (score 0):

**Root Cause of Failure:** On click, the window opens in new tab. You are trying to perform `.sendKeys` in the parent tab. Hence exception `unable to locate element`

**Solution:** You need to switch to the new tab and then perform `.sendKeys` action
Use the below code to switch to new tab/window

```
        String tab =driver.getWindowHandle(); // Store your parent tab
        String newTab = null;
        Set<String> handles = driver.getWindowHandles(); // get all tab handles
                    Iterator<String> iterator = handles.iterator();
                    while (iterator.hasNext()){
                        newTab = iterator.next();
                    }
        driver.switchTo().window(newTab); // switch to new tab
```

**Full working code:** Use the below code, it works as expected in my machine

```
        String tab =driver.getWindowHandle(); // Store your parent tab
        String newTab = null;
        WebElement jetztBestellenButton = driver.findElement(
                By.xpath("/html/body/main/div[8]/div/section/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[5]/a"));
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", jetztBestellenButton);
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        
        Set<String> handles = driver.getWindowHandles(); // get all tab handles
                    Iterator<String> iterator = handles.iterator();
                    while (iterator.hasNext()){
                        newTab = iterator.next();
                    }
        driver.switchTo().window(newTab); // switch to new tab
        js.executeScript("arguments[0].value='20095';", driver.findElement(By.name("deliveryAddress.zip")));
```

**Note:** In case you want to switch to parent tab, then just use below code

```
driver.switchTo().window(tab);
```

**Result output:**

[image]

**UPDATE:** Add the below lines of code at the end, this will enable the <kbd>prüfen</kbd> button

```
js.executeScript("arguments[0].value='20095';", driver.findElement(By.name("deliveryAddress.zip")));
```

After the above line, add the below 3 lines

```
Thread.sleep(2000);
driver.findElement(By.name("deliveryAddress.zip")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.name("deliveryAddress.zip")).sendKeys("20095");
```

Comment: Is this line working at your end `js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", jetztBestellenButton);`?

Comment: Hey Shawn, thank you very much, that's worked! One last question: How can be rewrite it so that the script also presses enter? Enter must be pressed so that the button (Check) appears on the page, which then checks this, whether the entered address works and this can move on to the next page. Maybe with: .sendKeys(Keys.ENTER) ?

Comment: @OkanAydin - Check the updated answer. It worked in my machine. 'prüfen' button enables. Try it and let me know if it works.

Comment: Hey Shawn, it worked! I appreccaite that thank you. But there ist one last misstake. As soon as the command is executed, the fields are filled automatically. In the input field "house number" is then automatically a 1. How can I delete the input field by code and then insert a self-selected number there? I had tried it as follows, but it did not work: 
driver.findElement(By.id("downshift-3-input")).clear();
         driver.findElement(By.id("downshift-3-input")).sendKeys("27");
         Thread.sleep(2000);

Comment: These are different issues. If you want to get advise from a wider community experts, you need to ask it as a new question, that way many others can see the question and advise you. Since your original question has been answered you can accept this answer and start a new question for latest issue you have.